# How to solved something went wrong when using guzzle in POST API?

Tags: php, json, guzzle

My framework is codeigniter and I make libraries like this:

```
function checkOut($url, $params){
        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'headers' => [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ,'Accept' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'],
            'verify' => false,
            'cookies' => true
        ]);

        $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
            'json' => $params
        ]);

        return $response->getBody->getContents();
    }
```

I call that libraries in my controller like this:

```
$dataArray is some array was i make,

$response_checkout = $this->corekredivo->checkOut($url, $dataArray)
```

and in view I just parsing to view like this:

```
$data = array(
            '_respon' => $response_checkout
        );]
```

But, when `var_dump();` in view the result is:

> string(90) "{"status": "ERROR", "error": {"message": "Something went
>   wrong.", "kind": "APIException"}}"

Before that I tried in a postman and succeeded and the structure of the arrays used is the same.

Comment: *Please refer this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135826/348234) to learn about accepting answer. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that this string (`"{"status": "ERROR", "error": {"message": "Something went wrong.", "kind": "APIException"}}"`) is a valid server response.

I mean that there no error from you side, you get this response from the server. Something went wrong inside the server app and you got this message.

To me it seems that you should be aware of this type of responses and process them somehow in your app.